# Why is my `.bashrc` run when switching to bash but not sh from a csh launched from Jenkins?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I am currently set-up Jenkins to checkout and run a compile, link and execute script from my project (say x script). The script uses a bunch of environment variables to execute. Our default shell is csh and above script is also in c shell.

So far it is good. Now, I have created a Jenkins build job and I have added #!/bin/csh so that another shell can call and execute the script. Jenkins by default uses sh shell to run the commands. So, how do I ensure that all the environment variables available in my c shell are visible under sh shell?
This is the simplest option for me ...

Option 2 - I can create a sh start-up script so that when Jenkins starts, it can get these environment variables defined automatically. So, to test this, I created 2 files under my home directory -- .profile and .bash_profile

When I switch from c shell to bourne shell by typing sh, none of the start up scripts are getting executed. However, this is true only for sh shell. For bash shell, .bashrc contents are getting executed.

Sample code below:

.bash_profile

```
echo "hello shrc"

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
# User specific aliases and functions
```

.profile

```
echo "hello shrc"
.bashrc
```

Commands results below:

```
sharanb@clnx1 /u25/sharanb ->sh
sh-4.1$
```

Note nothing gets echoed above

```
sharanb@clnx1 /u25/sharanb ->bash
hello bashrc
[sharanb@clnx1 ~]$
```

Note how .bashrc gets executed.

Need help and guidance

Comment: Environment variables (as opposed to shell variables) are *always* exported to child processes. You don't need to do anything explicitly. Your problem here has nothing to do with environment variables -- they're inherited from the parent process -- but would appear to relate to regular shell variables.

Comment: That said, if you want `sh` to run an arbitrary script at startup, put the name of that script in the environment variable `ENV`.

Comment: ...so, you can and should configure Jenkins itself to export the variables you want itself, and *not* rely on any dotfiles or such -- if Jenkins sets them up, they'll be available no matter what shell you're using, or even if you're invoking a non-shell tool from Jenkins directly.

Comment: (Environment variables, as their name implies, are part of the *process environment*; they're not a shell construct, but actually something the OS itself provides, and are available to all UNIX applications, not shells only. The only special support is that shells automatically create shell variables for every environment variable they inherit, and automatically re-export updates to the environment whenever a shell variable also in the environment is modified).

Comment: One additional question is - if I am executing a c shell script from sh shell then I would assume the environment variables would be still visible when c shell is executing

Comment: **Environment** variables are exposed to subprocesses, yes. If you haven't exported a variable to the environment, then it's just a shell variable, and process-local.